# Get sql values before wpf page loads

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application that takes in information from a database. When I first load the application on the default window, I have TextBoxes that needs to be filled by data, but the textboxes wont get populated, So I was wondering, How would I go about getting the value before the page even loads, then setting the textbox text property to the data.
I have my LINQ to SQL Code inside a try and catch block like this:

```
try
{
   MY LINQ TO SQL CODE HERE:
}
catch
{

}
```

I literally Have to do it like this, as If I dont do it like this and just put the SQL Code, I get a timeout error. So since I need to do this, My sql code isnt running before the page loads, but after it loads. How can I get it to run my code before the window is ever loaded, So that way I could set my textbox values?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using an [asynchronous binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync.aspx) for this.  It's even built in to XAML syntax, like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyBinding,IsAsync=True,FallbackValue=Loading...}" />
```

Now let's say the *MyBinding* property runs your SQL:

```
string _myBinding = null;
public string MyBinding {
    get {
        if (_myBinding == null)
        {
            // get value from SQL operation
        }
        return _myBinding;
    }
}
```

Now your TextBox will display the fallback value ("Loading..."), and the UI will not block, but will load when your SQL operation is complete.

It's probably better to take this approach rather than blocking the UI while the SQL operation runs (users might think your app is frozen, get frustrated, etc).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I tried using your code and got quite a lot of errors, and was wondering is it ok If I used my own code something like the try and catch blocks, then set the Textbox binding path to reference my query, Or will I specifically need to use the code you provided in order for it to work properly? Thanks

Comment: Edit: I got it to work by putting the string name inside the block... Also it has not worked,  The TextBox just has a loading Text on it, but the data isnt yet binded onto it Any ideas?

Comment: @MarkMackanga yes, should be fine.  Just intended this code as an example.

Comment: @MarkMackanga you mentioned you get a timeout error.  Do you think it could be a SQL timeout?  That's another issue

Comment: Hi, yeah its a SQL Timeout, as even when Im connecting through Management studio I get a timeout, and have to connect again a second time for it to finally connect. Any Ideas what I could do about that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place your query code in the constructor that's called when you instantiate the window.

```
public class myWindow : Window
{
    public myWindow()
    {
         //code here
         InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I suggest that you show a loading screen or something of the sort while you're query is executed and a failure screen / message if your query fails.